# Qt::Drawer type window signal on User-driven close

Tags: qt

Is there a signal being emitted when a user drags a Qt::Drawer type window (OSX specific) enough to close it? I need to capture that in my app so that I can trigger my "open" button again.

Answer (score 0):

Is your drawer widget getting a [close event](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qwidget.html#closeEvent)?

If so, then you can key off that (by emitting a custom signal or otherwise).

Comment: It's not receiving a close even when the user resizes the drawer window by hand just enough for "hide" it.... and doesn't receive the hideEvent either....

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is emitting a [QDragEnterEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qdragenterevent.html)